# missing content in ionic nested views

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I am nesting views with ionic v1.3.
here is parent html

```
<h2>welcome </h2>

  <ion-nav-view name="welcomeCreate"></ion-nav-view>

  <ion-nav-view name="welcomeJoin"></ion-nav-view>

  <button class="button button-full button-positive" > start </button>

<h2> welcome again </h2>
```

Problem :
the ion-nav view is injected correctly but i do not see

```
<button class="button button-full button-positive" > start </button>

<h2> welcome again </h2>
```

Question 
Why ionic is not consider the rest of my html page ?

Rest of the context :
here is my routing config

```
     .state('welcome', {
        url: "/welcome",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: "templates/start/welcome.html"
      })

      .state('welcome.create', {
        url: '/create',
        views: {
          'welcomeCreate': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/start/welcomeCreate.html'
          }
        }
      })

      .state('welcome.join', {
        url: '/join',
        views: {
          'welcomeJoin': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/start/welcomeJoin.html'
          }
        }
      })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Your requirement is multiple named views. Following document is useful
>   to implement multiple views in a single page
>   https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views

More about this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33677362/ionic-multiple-view-in-same-page).